# failed calling webhook "vingress.elbv2.k8s.aws"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I installed aws-load-balancer-controller on new EKS cluster (version v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b).

I installed by this guide https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.3/deploy/installation/ step by step but when I'm trying to deploy ingress object I'm getting the error I mentioned in the title.
I tried to do as github issues questions like here https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/2039 but didn't find any answer.

What else can I do for checking this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In case it might help others - I also had the original issue using fargate profile and worker-node for core-dns. The solution for me I found in another place was just adding

```
node_security_group_additional_rules = {
  ingress_allow_access_from_control_plane = {
    type                          = "ingress"
    protocol                      = "tcp"
    from_port                     = 9443
    to_port                       = 9443
    source_cluster_security_group = true
    description                   = "Allow access from control plane to webhook port of AWS load balancer controller"
  }
}
```

Comment: It helped me a lot, was stuck far too much time on this, thanks @Emo!

Comment: This still works today. I was getting webhook errors and this fixed those errors.

Comment: How did you add this?

Comment: This answer is Terraform, it comes from [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/2039) on the AWS LB controller.   A follow up to the original answer shows the [AWS console equivalent](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/2039#issuecomment-1189524910).

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are getting an error message like the following, if is not the case, please post your error.

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "anymanifest.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "vingress.elbv2.k8s.aws": Post "https://aws-load-balancer-webhook-service.kube-system.svc:443/validate-networking-v1beta1-ingress?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
```

Usually, it happens due to EKS control plane can't communicate with nodes using the webhook port.

Checkout the logs of the aws-load-balancer-controller pods to check the port it started to listen

```
{"level":"info","ts":1643365219.2410042,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"serving webhook server","host":"","port":9443}
```

In order to fix that, in the security group of the worker nodes, allow communications of port `9443` from EKS control plane

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I've analysed the same issue this way:

1. I've decribed the `aws-load-balancer-webhook-service` k8s Service, and I saw it had **no endpoints**
2. I looked to the `aws-load-balancer-controller` k8s Deployment, it was stuck to **0/0 replicas** :/
3. I've described the `aws-load-balancer-controller` Replicaset, the following error was raised by the *replicaset-controller*:

```
Error creating: pods "aws-load-balancer-controller-XXX-" is forbidden: error looking up service account kube-system/aws-load-balancer-controller: service account "aws-load-balancer-controller" not found
```

4. So I checked the service account creation step, and I saw that the CloudFormation process (done by `eksctl create iamserviceaccount --name=aws-load-balancer-controller ...`) had failed
   (Stack name: `eksctl-<CLUSTER_NAME>-addon-iamserviceaccount-kube-system-aws-load-balancer-controller`)
5. It was because the add-on repository was wrong (bad account number)
   Choose the right one here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-ons-images.html

Then, to apply the fix, I've:

1. Deleted the `eksctl-<CLUSTER_NAME>-addon-iamserviceaccount-kube-system-aws-load-balancer-controller` CloudFormation stack
2. Launched the `eksctl create iamserviceaccount --name=aws-load-balancer-controller` command again
3. Scaled the `aws-load-balancer-controller` Replicaset from 0 to 2

And it worked ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! In my case, the cause of the issue was the re-use of an existing role name in the `eksctl create iamserviceaccount` command.

Answer (score 0):

load-balancer-controller pod description for more details
It may happen that the image is not available at the ECR

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow up to the accepted answer. If you are not using fargate or are confused by the answer itself, the [original source](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/2462#issuecomment-1031624085) refers to a Terraform script

To apply this solution from AWS Console:

1. Locate the cluster's security group. take note of the ID

[image: Security group of nodes and cluster]

2. Select the **NODE's** security group and edit the inbound connections.
3. Add a new rule: Custom TCP 9443, put as source the cluster security group ID

[image: The inbound rules will look like this as a result]